# Data in Fragment ViewPager need 3 times to refresh android

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have viewpager with 3 fragments in it. Then in fragment 3 I have data query to the firebase database with singleValueEventListener. 
But the problem is when I'm updating the data in fragment 3 from the firebase database. Then open the app, The data does not update directly. I need to open and close the app 3 times, then the data gets updated.

Another case to update the data is, I have to go to fragment 3 - fragment 1 - then go back to fragment 3. And the data is updated.

Then in fragment 3 , I have swipe refresh . To refresh the data , I also need 2 times swipe before the data updated

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_course");
        users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mataKuliahRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("courses");
        daftarPengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman");
        pengumumanRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pengumuman_course");
        mFlagPengumuman = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("flag_pengumuman");

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

        View b= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).tabThree;
        badge = new BadgeView(getActivity(), b);
        badge.setBadgeMargin(90,0);
        badge.setTextSize(10);



        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override public void run() {
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        listPengumuman.clear();
                        consolidatedList.clear();
                        LoadDataPengumuman();


                    }
                    private void onLoaded() {
                        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, 500);
            }
        });

        counter = new Counter() {
            @Override
            public void setCounter(int count) {
                Log.e("Ser_Counter", "total countnya " + asd);
                Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk count ");
                asd=asd+count;
                if(asd==0){
                    Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk asd=0");
                    badge.hide();

                }else{
                    Log.e("Ser_Counter", "masuk asd=else");

                    badge.setText(asd + "");
                    badge.show();
                }

            }
        };



        mJumlahPengumuman = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jumlah_pengumuman);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.PengumumanRView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        adapter = new myAdapterPengumuman(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), consolidatedList,counter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewHeader header = (RecyclerViewHeader) v.findViewById(R.id.header3);
        header.attachTo(mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        LoadDataPengumuman();

        return v;
    }
```

I don't know whats wrong here, please help.

Comment: There is likely a problem with your code in fragment 3

Comment: Share your code, so that we can look into it

Comment: you can check my code

Answer (score 0):

> You can not change data of Fragment-3 from Fragment-1 because ViewPager can only activate Fragment-2.

Lets say you are on Page-5 ViewPager can only activate Page 4 and Page-6 not others.

Comment: Are u sure, u understand about my question?